# Decision boundaries for nearest centroid

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to draw decision boundaries for different classifiers including the `nearestcentroid`, but when I use this code

```
if hasattr(clf, "decision_function"):
            Z = clf.decision_function(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
        else:
            Z = clf.predict_proba(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])[:, 1]
```

I get an error saying  *'NearestCentroid' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'*. How can I fix this?

Comment: why you think if not hasattr `decision_function` then always hasattr `predict_proba`?

Comment: @BearBrown I got it from scikit learn tutorial, plotting different classifiers but `nearestcentroid` wasn't among them, so I am wondering what is the problem. I don't understand what is the difference between them and also what if I only use `Z = clf.predict(numpy.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])`. I don't know which one is correct to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own `predict_proba`:

```
from sklearn.utils.extmath import softmax
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances

def predict_proba(self, X):
    distances = pairwise_distances(X, self.centroids_, metric=self.metric)
    probs = softmax(distances)
    return probs

clf = NearestCentroid()
clf.predict_proba = predict_proba.__get__(clf)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf.predict_proba(X_test)
```

Comment: `softmax(-distances)` makes more sense, so the probability is higher for the nearer centroids.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your X has two features, you can generate a [`meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html#numpy.meshgrid) where each axis pertains to one of the features.

Assuming `X` is your features array with two features - shape would be (N, 2), where N is the number of samples - and `y` is your target array.:

```
# first determine the min and max boundaries for generating the meshgrid
feat1_min, feat1_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
feat2_min, feat2_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
```

Now generate your meshgrid and make predictions along the grid:

```
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(feat1_min, feat1_max , 0.02),
                     np.arange(feat2_min, feat2_max , 0.02))  # 0.02 is step size
Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
```

Now make the plot:

```
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.figure()
plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap="autumn")
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, cmap="autumn",
            edgecolor='k', s=10)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! I was confused with the use of   `clf.decision_functions` and `clf.predict_proba`. So we won't use them here.

Comment: No problem! The `decision_function` and `predict_proba` depends on the classifier you're using in sklearn. Not all of them will have those methods.

Answer (score 1):

As BearBrown pointed out, you only check if "decison_function" is an attribute of **clf**. You never check if "predict_proba" is an attribute of **clf**

```
if hasattr(clf, "decision_function"):
    Z = clf.decision_function(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
elif hasattr(clf, "predict_proba"): # This condition ensures that you'll see that predict_proba is not an attribute of clf`enter code here`
    Z = clf.predict_proba(numpy.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])[:, 1]
else: #This will show you your error again
    raise AttributeError("Neither 'decision_function' not 'predict_proba' found in clf")
```

After this, you should check why what you expect is not an attrib of **clf**

Comment: @MuhamadAli I still get an error and I cannot plot decision boundaries. How can I plot the decision boundaries in this case? If I only use `Z = clf.predict(numpy.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])` I can see the figures but I don't think this would be correct. Do you have any solutions for this?

Comment: Could you make a minimum example so that it's easy to see what's expected?

Comment: yes, I was trying to use this to plot the figure below (in @Scratch'N'Purr's answer.) But I guess I shouldn't use these and should only stick to `Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])` because when I want to plot my decision boundaries it looks weird if I use `clf.decision_functions` and `clf.predict_proba`.